# Creating an instance of an C# Enum with no 0 value

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I need to create an instance of an Enum class that hasn't got a 0 value. With a 0 value, next code works fine:

```
ObjectFactory.CreateInstance("Edu3.DTOModel.Schedule.ScheduleStateEnum");
```

Enum:

```
namespace Edu3.DTOModel.Schedule
{
    public enum ScheduleStateEnum
    {
        DUMMY = 0,
        Draft = 1,
        Published = 2,
        Archived = 3
    }
}
```

If I comment out DUMMY, Creating the instance doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to create an instance of an Enum class that hasn't got a 0 value.

Assuming an enum like this:

```
public enum ScheduleStateEnum
{
    Draft = 1,
    Published = 2,
    Archived = 3
}
```

you can create an instance like this:

```
ScheduleStateEnum myState = 0;
```

If you cannot declare a variable of the type and you need to access the type as a string (as in your example), use `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
var myState = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(
                  "Edu3.DTOModel.Schedule.ScheduleStateEnum"));
```

Of course, both of these options will give you an instance that actually has the integer value `0`, even if the enum doesn’t declare one. If you want it to default to one of the values you have actually declared, you need to use Reflection to find it, for example:

```
var myState = Type.GetType("Edu3.DTOModel.Schedule.ScheduleStateEnum")
                  .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                  .First()
                  .GetValue(null);
```

This will crash for enums that have no values at all defined. Use `FirstOrDefault` and check for `null` if you want to prevent this.

Comment: I would recommend using `Enum` methods to construct instances and get available values, i.e. `Enum.ToObject(type, 0)` and `Enum.GetValues(type)`.

Answer (score 5):

It's a problem with your ObjectFactory class, because

`Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Edu3.DTOModel.Schedule.ScheduleStateEnum))`

works fine and creates int 0.

Comment: You sure, because TomTom says it's not possible without a 0 value.

Comment: please try your code before posting, especially before claiming that something “works fine”. There is no overload of `Activator.CreateInstance` that takes a single string.

Comment: @Lieven - just try it, like I did. A new enum is just the zero value, even if zero value mapping is not defined. I think Tomtom meant lije me "it's not possible it does not work", not "It's not possible to do this". I don't known why people downvoted my answer...

Comment: @Timwi - I actually tried it but copied back with an error. It does not change the root of the problem. If ObjectFactory can get to the Type with the string, it can create it without a zero name.

Comment: I’ve removed the downvote because you fixed your answer. Would you please explain why you downvoted mine?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is not possible. Enum is per definition a value field, so it has to ahve a way to initialize it with a 0 numerical value.

Comment: This is just flat out wrong. In .net you can assign *any* integer value to an Enum no matter what values are defined for it.

Comment: @Nick Please Learn Reading. Or logic. I never said you can not assign any value.

Comment: Question: How do I create an instance of an Enum class that hasn't got a 0 value?
Your answer: "Actually it is not possible."
It absolutely **is** possible because an Enum can have *ANY* value, including 0, even if it doesn't have a zero defined for it.

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to provide a zero valued enum member - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182149%28VS.80%29.aspx for details.  Is there any reason you don't want a zero valued member such as None?

Comment: Well, I could definitely use None. I start at 1 because the Enum reflects a Table in my Database.